WSO2 developer studio: Is it possible to open a CAR file in WSO2 developer studio?
Is it possible to open a CAR file in WSO2 developer studio?
Can any one share me the process. I have production ESB_CAR_Prod_1.1.3.car file which i need to open and view?
I tried to install WSO2 developer studio and open the file.
So far i am able to open the xml file in ecliplse.
